# Issues after giving update app from AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, release

All,

We have an app in Appstore which is functional,  Now we have build the app for new Version with complete new architecture, Design. Every thing is changed. Now we have given a update for out existing app in the Appstore. App went live and we updated the current app in Phone, We got the new version as expected.

But the problem starts here. In the Updated app we are not able to login and some other services are not working.

But if we download as new app (I mean deleting the old app and download it again). Every thing is working as expected, like login, and all the services.

We are not understanding what went wrong. What may the issue, Can any one help us.

Comment: Are you using core data ?

Comment: In previous we didnt used any storage part, Now we are using sqlite and Realm, But for login we are not using any thing

Comment: That rules our migration issues i guess :D

Comment: But the code is completley different, We can say it as compltley different project

Comment: Make sure that you handle all the old data that remain on the phone during an upgrade, and migrate them to your new formats where necessary. Think about: Settings, Core Data, local files, etc. Don't forget about any libraries that you are using that store their own data. Also, test the upgrade in XCode, so you can see what goes wrong